# How to subscribe to a topic whom type is gazebo_msg/ContactState

Tags: ros, sensor, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody

I'm trying to write a subscriber following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) to listen to a topic which is published by a contact sensor (libgazebo_ros_bumper.so). Here is the structure of this topic shown in "topic monitor":

[image: image description]

Assuming that we want to write the size of ContactState message published by this topic, I wrote this program and compiled it (using catkin_make command) successfully:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "gazebo_msgs/ContactState.h"
#include <sstream>

void chatterCallback(const gazebo_msgs::ContactState cs)
{
  int a;
  a = sizeof(cs);
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << a;
  ROS_INFO("The size of recieved ContactState message is: %d", a);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("contact_sensor_state", 1000, chatterCallback);
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

However, Nothing happen whenever I run this subscriber node using rosrun command. It seems that  ROS never call chatterCallback function. How should I edit `ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("contact_sensor_state", 1000, chatterCallback);` to fix this issue?

I also have 2 more simple question regarding the above question:

1. How can I store the valued published by "contact_sensor_state/states/[0]/total_wrench/force/z" in a double variable in my program? *(Shay answered this question)*
2. Is it possible to advertise a variable in my program? I mean is it possible for a node to be both a subscriber and publisher. If yes, how should I edit the code to do this?   *(Shay answered this question)*

I'm using ROS indigo, gazebo 2.2 and ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244380/how-to-subscribe-to-a-topic-whom-type-is-gazebo_msg/contactstate/) by [Masoud](https://answers.ros.org/users/26841/masoud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message variable should be a reference variable. You can refer to the code below.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "gazebo_msgs/ContactState.h"
#include <sstream>

void chatterCallback(const gazebo_msgs::ContactStateConstPtr& cs)
{
  int a;
  a = sizeof(cs);
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << a;
  ROS_INFO("The size of recieved ContactState message is: %d", a);

  double z = cs->states[0].total_wrench.force.z; //here is for you question 1).
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("contact_sensor_state", 1000, chatterCallback);

  ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("mymsg",1000); //here is for you question 2).
  std_msgs::String msg = "Hello"; //here is for you question 2).

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  while (ros::ok())
  {
      pub.publish(msg); //here is for you question 2).

      ros::spinOnce();
      loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2